# Different Data Models in In-Memory Cache and In Persistence Layer in Apache Ignite Data Grid

Tags: java, caching, persistence, ignite

In apache ignite data grid, it has read-through and write through features that means if I update anything in in-memory layer, eventually the update will be written in persistence layer. It works perfectly if I have same data model in both of the in-memory and persistence layer.
But I want to have two different model in in-memory cache and persistence layer and want it to have data grid like behavior. If I update anything in the in-memory, I want to have this update written in specific part of persistence layer.

I have gone through the documentation and found out about the custom **CacheStore** implementation but not sure how to achieve the above requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think custom CacheStore might help you here, check this [Implementing Custom Cache Store](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/persistence/custom-cache-store) docs.

As the documentation suggests, it's better to start with `CacheStoreAdapter<K, V>` and implement the `load` and `write` methods just the way you like.